# AS Rock Z97 Pro 4 does not boot sometimes

Tags: boot, motherboard, battery

Main board: https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z97%20Pro4/

Hello,

Sometimes my PC does not boot, there are just 2 short beeps.
After I insert or remove the battery of the mainboard it works again.
("Or", because if the battery is inserted I remove it, if not I insert it.)
Then it boots again 2 or 3 times, but it still beeps 12 times. (3 short beeps 4 times)
Does anyone know if there is some way to fix this?

Thank you for your precious time.
Lukas Hohl

Comment: Have you considered just replacing the CMOS battery.  Based on the chipset, your motherboard is at least 5 years old, CMOS batteries have a limited lifespan.

Comment: I did change it 2 times, but it did not help.

Comment: Check your memory. [ASRock Z97 Pro4 BIOS Beep Codes | DDR4Motherboard](https://ddr4motherboard.com/beepcodes/ASROCK-Z97-PRO4)